# Make iPad App Universal (Xcode 5)

Tags: ipad, xcode5, universal

I am struggling to find help with converting my basic iPad app into a Universal one. Lots of info on iPhone to universal, but not the other way around. Really hope I don't have to start over. The references I have found aren't for Xcode 5.

Any help would be really appreciated. This is my first app.

Jen

Comment: Well add `<viewcontroller>~iphone.xib` for view controllers that you can't reuse directly on the iPhone. and for the rest just follow the iPhone to iPad tutorials. The idea is the same.

Comment: Please excuse my lack of knowledge but I can't find any reference to an xib for my app...

Comment: Are you using storeyboards? it will work in the same as nib. `<storyboard>~iphone.storyboard`

Comment: yes I am using storyboards. So create a duplicate storyboard? :-/

Comment: Yes that is an option, or use size class. But those are iOS 8 only.

Comment: Thanks. Are you able to give me a hint on the best way to move forward? Is it best to duplicate the storyboard and how do I do this?

Comment: There is no best way, only the way you find convenient.

Comment: Ok I understand. How do I then duplicate the storyboard to make an iPhone version?

Comment: I'm not going to walk you thru it, but just add an new one or copy the ipad version and rename the copy. This is not that hard, so just go an try thing and not just ask every little step.